# Redis blpop sometimes return tuple, sometime not?

Tags: python, json, redis

I use the following code to place/retrieve items in my Redis queue but I sometime get an error when decoding the json dump, because the item returned is not a tuple but the full json.

Here's the class :

```
class RedisQueue(object):
    """Simple Queue with Redis Backend"""
    def __init__(self, namespace, redis_url='redis://127.0.0.1:6379'):
        self.__db = redis.from_url(redis_url)
        self.redis_url = redis_url
        self.namespace = namespace

    def put(self, queue, item):
        """Put item into the queue."""
        self.__db.rpush('{0}:{1}'.format(self.namespace, queue), json.dumps(item))

    def get(self, queue, block=True, timeout=None):
        """Remove and return an item from the queue.

        If optional args block is true and timeout is None (the default), block
        if necessary until an item is available."""
        key = '{0}:{1}'.format(self.namespace, queue)
        if block:
            item = self.__db.blpop(key, timeout=timeout)
        else:
            item = self.__db.lpop(key)

        if item is not None:
            try:
                item = json.loads(item[1])
            except ValueError as e:
                sys.stderr.write("[ERROR JSON (in queue)] - {1} => {0}\n".format(str(e), str(item)))
                return None

        return item
```

I sometime get an exception at :

```
    if item is not None:
        try:
            item = json.loads(item[1])
        except ValueError as e:
            sys.stderr.write("[ERROR JSON (in queue)] - {1} => {0}\n".format(str(e), str(item)))
            return None
```

That says :

```
[ERROR JSON (in queue)] - {"ip": null, "domain": "somedomain.com", "name": "Some user name", "contact_id": 12345, "signature": 
"6f496a4eaba2c1ea4e371ea2c4951ad92f41ddf45ff4949ffa761b0648a22e38"} => end is out of bounds
```

This is because item is the full json, so json.loads(item[₁]) causes the error. But it occurs only from time to time, not everytime. And when I manually checked the value of item, I had a tuple with the key in 0, and the value (the json string) in 1, which is expected.

Why, sometime, redis returns the value in item, and sometime a tuple with `key,value` ?

Comment: `lpop` returns always the value only.

Comment: ahahahhaaah ... but .. seriously ?! why the difference ?!

Comment: Oh, and if you want, explain the difference as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are issuing two different commands, and each command returns something different.

[`LPOP`](http://redis.io/commands/blpop) returns the item popped. It only takes a single key. [`BLPOP`](http://redis.io/commands/blpop) however can be ran against multiple lists. Therefore it returns an array of the list the item was popped from, and the item popped. If the timeout expires, however, and no item was available, it returns a nil bulk array.

The documentation on this is quite readily available at the above links. I highly recommend checking the Redis docs for the commands you use to be sure you understand the differences between similar yet distinct commands.

In your code you will call one of the above commands, but not always the same one. So sometimes you will get a tuple, and others a string. When you block:  tuple. When you don't: string.

To preserve consistency of the return value's type, I would instead always call `BLPOP` but instead of a boolean, go with either the user specified timeout, or in case of no desire to block, a block timeout of 0. Then you will always get a tuple back, though you will have to catch the `IndexError` you would get when trying to access the second element of an empty tuple. A standard try/except clause should do it.

Answer (score 2):

The redis code is tricky.
When you use `blpop(key)` , it turns into `blpop([key])`, and the return value of this command is the name of the queue (which is the key) plus the value in this key: {'key': value1}

In the case of you call `blpop([key1, key2, key3])`, if the key3 has values, then the return value of this command is the name of key3, plus the value in key3: {'key3': value2}

So **`blpop` always return tuple.**

When you use `lpop(key)`, it only return the value in this key: value

I don't like the way that redis is compatible to have blpop(key) one parameter, and secretly treat it as blpop([key]). I prefer it to force the program to write into `blpop([key])`.